# Validar dados e gerar senha temporária - cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

Bom dia,

estou precisando criar uma função que valide os campos do cliente e compara para vefificar se estão corretos se estiverem, gerar uma senha temporária.

Segue abaixo meu código.

```
function _gerar_senha_validando_campos(){

        if (!empty($this->data['Cliente']['codcontrato']) && !empty($this->data['Cliente']['cpf_cnpj']) && !empty($this->data['Cliente']['login']) && !empty($this->data['Cliente']['ip'])) {

            $cliente = $this->Cliente->find(array('situacao'=>'APR', 'codcontrato' => $this->data['Cliente']['codcontrato']));

        if (($this->data['cliente']['codcontrato'] == $cliente['cliente']['codcontrato']) &&
            ($this->data['cliente']['cpf_cnpj'] == $cliente['cliente']['cpf_cnpj']) &&
            ($this->data['cliente']['login'] == $cliente['cliente']['login']) && 
            ($this->data['cliente']['ip'] == $cliente['cliente']['ip'])) {

        $CaracteresAceitos = 'acefghijrsuxz23456789';
        $max = strlen($CaracteresAceitos)-1;
        $password = null;
        for($i=0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $password .= $CaracteresAceitos{mt_rand(0, $max)};
        }

        return $password;

        $this->set('sucesso', 'Senha alterada com sucesso!');
        $this->set('newAviso','ATENÇÃO: Sua senha é temporária e vai expirar-se em 2 horas. Você deverá efetuar a troca da senha no site da Virtual Telecom ou clicando AQUI.');

        } 

        if (($this->data['cliente']['codcontrato'] != $cliente['cliente']['codcontrato'])) {
            $this->set('erro', 'Código do contrato inválido!');
        }

        if (($this->data['cliente']['cpf_cnpj'] != $cliente['cliente']['cpf_cnpj'])) {
            $this->set('erro', 'CPF inválido!');
        }

        if (($this->data['cliente']['login'] != $cliente['cliente']['login'])) {
            $this->set('erro', 'Login inválido!');
        }

        if (($this->data['cliente']['ip'] != $cliente['cliente']['ip'])) {
            $this->set('erro', 'IP diferente do cadastrado!');
        }

        else{

            $this->set('erro', 'Dados não conferem! Favor Verificar novamente');
        }

    }

        else{

            $this->set('erro', 'Campos obrigatórios não preenchidos');

    }

}
```

Comment: Você poderia ser mais claro quanto ao problema, dúvida ou caminho que quer tomar em si? Essa senha temporária seria enviada por e-mail ou mostrada na tela mesmo? Se for o caso, mandar senhas por e-mail (como texto puro), não é uma boa prática. Mas de qualquer forma especifica melhor o objetivo da questão por favor.

Comment: Essa senha será gerada na tela do usuário, basicamente quando o usuário inserir os dados, quero verificar se os dados digitados estão corretos, caso estiverem irá gerar um alert informando ( senha alterada com sucesso! sua senha é $senha ) Favor efetuar a senha pois terá validade de duas horas.

Comment: eu tenho um view que o usuário passa as informações para validar os dados caso o mesmo esqueça a senha. mas para gerar uma nova senha o usuário tem que confirmar seus dados, estando ok o sistema irá gerar um senha temporária para o mesmo, com isso o usuário vai acessar com essa senha e efetuar a troca no sistema posteriormente.

Comment: Certo, primeiramente o `return $password` deve ficar por ultimo.

Comment: Poderia me mostrar respondendo e exemplificando no código por favor?

Comment: Assim que tiver tempo, faço isso